# Rebuild code with for loops instead of reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, reduce

Challenge: Construct a function intersection that compares input arrays and returns a new array with elements found in all of the inputs.

After finding a solution using the reduce method, I tried to rebuild the code *without* using the reduce method - it didn't work. Where did I go wrong? Can the desired outcome be achived using the rudimentary approach I tried?

Here's the original solution.

```js
function intersection1 (arrayOfArrays) {
    return arrayOfArrays.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {


      const newArr = [];

      accumulator.forEach((ele)=>{
        if (currentValue.includes(ele)) { 
          result.push(ele);
        };
      })
      return result;
    });
  }
  const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
  const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
  const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
  console.log(intersection1([arr1, arr2, arr3])); // should log: [5, 15]
```

I tried the following approach but it doesn't work. It doesn't log: [5, 15] but just: 1

```js
function intersection (arrayOfArrays) {
    const newArr = [];
    let cache1 = [];
    let cache2 = [];
    let cache3 = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
      return cache1.push(arrayOfArrays[i]);
      
    }    

    for (let j = 1; j < arrayOfArrays.length; j++) {
      return cache2.push(arrayOfArrays[j]);

    }

    for (let n = 2; n <= arrayOfArrays.length; n++) {
      return cache3.push(arrayOfArrays[n]);

    }
    cache1.forEach((ele) => {
      if (cache2.includes(ele) && cache3.includes(ele)) {
        newArr.push(ele);
      }
    });
    return newArr;
  }

  const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
  const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
  const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
  console.log(intersection([arr1, arr2, arr3])); // should log: [5, 15]
```

Comment: Protip: set operations (like intersection) can be implemented efficiently by using a `Set` object to allow you to perform tests for set membership in `O(1)` time instead of `O(n)` time.

Comment: Instead of declaring three `cacheN` variables with separate arrays, and writing different code for them, you really should keep the original approach of looping over an `accumulator` inside a of a loop over the `arrayOfArrays`

Comment: Your first snippet does not appear to work either. Is `result` the same as `newArr`?

Comment: `return cache1.push` will exit the function. It will not loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you wanted to do with the second solution is more like this:

Replacing `cache1`, `cache2`, `cache3` with *first*, *second* and *third* item of the input array:

```js
function intersection (arrayOfArrays) {
    const newArr = [];
    let cache1 = arrayOfArrays[0]
    let cache2 = arrayOfArrays[1]
    let cache3 = arrayOfArrays[2]

    cache1.forEach((ele) => {
      if (cache2.includes(ele) && cache3.includes(ele)) {
        newArr.push(ele);
      }
    });
    return newArr;
  }

  const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
  const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
  const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
  console.log(intersection([arr1, arr2, arr3])); // log: [5, 15]
```

But as you know this function only works if you have fixed 3 number of arrays as an array for its argument.

we can rewrite this function in an other way but not be limited by the length of the input array:

```js
function intersection3(arrayOfArrays) {
  let result = arrayOfArrays[0];

  arrayOfArrays.forEach((arr) => {
    const newResult = [];
    arr.forEach((elm) => {
      if (result.includes(elm) && !newResult.includes(elm)) {
        newResult.push(elm);
      }
    });
    result = newResult;
  });

  return result;
}


  const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
  const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
  const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
  const arr4 = [1, 10, 15, 5];
  console.log(intersection3([arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4])); // log: [5, 15]
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Could we omit `&& !newResult.includes(elm)` from the if statement without losing functionality? Like this: `if (result.includes(elm)) { newResult.push(elm); }`

Comment: if we remove that part, it will accept duplication in the final result. try these two array: `arr1 = [1, 5, 5]` and `arr2 = [2, 5, 5]`